# Error en tiempo de ejecución en CODESYS

Tags: ejecutar, ingenieria-del-software

He instalado la versión 3.5.18.0 de codesys y al seleccionar **Simulation** y dar clic en **Loging** obtengo el siguiente error:

**Codesys simulation runtime exception**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo idea de como solucionarlo ya que en internet no hay información.

Mi sistema operativo es W10 x64.

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Este es un sitio de preguntas/respuestas referentes a código, aquí unas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Por otro lado, intenta con click derecho, propiedades, compatibilidad, ejecutar compatiblidad con 32 bits.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Para aquella persona que me dijo que aquí no es un foro para publicar preguntas sobre programas, le comento que no sabía. Estaba desesperado pues no encontraba la respuesta en ningún lugar.
Lo que me sirvió fue desinstalar el programa e instalar la versión de 32 bits, no me explico porqué sirvió ya que mi sistema operativo es de 64 bits.
Dejo la pregunta y la solución por si acaso a alguien mas le pasa lo mismo.